# not able to install chatterbot

Tags: python, pip, chatterbot

clang -c C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_fi88703\blis_4451c7d4e79d42318f42cf4cb7b4d41d\blis_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgugap_tu\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\ankit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_fi88703\blis_4451c7d4e79d42318f42cf4cb7b4d41d\blis_src\include\windows-x86_64
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[end of output]

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
  Failed to build preshed thinc blis
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

C:\Users\ankit>

i have tried many solutions given on stackoverflow, but none work